# How can I change the microphone and speaker settings of the web version of Facebook Messenger without making live calls?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I see the microphone and speaker settings only when I am on a live call. And, before I can change the settings, the call is disconnected.

I am not finding the settings options where I can fix those settings when I am not in a call.

How can I change the microphone and speaker settings of the web version of Facebook Messenger without making live calls?